# Отслеживание появления ошибки при вторичном вызове метода в тесте

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, testng

Как проверить на появление исключения?

У меня при втором вызове метода должна появиться ошибка. Если я сделаю так:

```
@Test(expected = MyError.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    this.myClass.initialize();
    this.myClass.initialize();
}
```

То тест пройдет, и ему без разницы, в первом или втором случае была ошибка.

Как проверить, что именно при втором вызове функции выпадает ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более стандартный и наглядный вариант, чтобы поймать ошибку именно на втором вызове:

```
@Test(expected = MyError.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    try {
        this.myClass.initialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка должна быть только на втором вызове!");
    }
    this.myClass.initialize();
}
```

Comment: А разве этоа аннотация не ждет от результата метода ошибку?@Test(expected = MyError.class)

Comment: Все верно. Тест однозначно гарантирует два момента: 1) при первом вызове метода не будет Exceiption "MyError.class". 2) при втором вызове будет exception "MyError.class".

Comment: Да нет, вроде все верно. Просто я с фреймворком слабо знаком. Код в другом ответе с наскоку понять проще )

Comment: В моем ответе в аннотации теста уже написано, что мы ожидаем исключение. Даже код теста читать не надо. То есть я и автор вопроса используем стандартную возможность JUnit. И это правильно! И наоборот, в ответе @JVic применяется довольно нестандартная конструкция catch+return. В которую надо еще въехать, чтобы понять что делает тест...

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev ну как показала практика "с наскоку" в мой ответ въехать проще)

Comment: @JVic, а по моему Ваш вариант сложен для понимания. return вообще лишний)

Answer (score 4):

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    this.myClass.initialize();
    try {
      this.myClass.initialize();
      Assert.fail("Should have thrown MyError");
    } catch (MyError e) {
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я же просто поймаю ошибку и продолжу тест, нет? Или можно вообще без try/catch, просто вызов метода и Asset следом?

Comment: @ks_on_v Вам нужно отловить ошибку и сказать что тест прошел, если ошибка возникнет во втором вызове, правильно? Мой метод как раз этим и занимается. А что вы планируете продолжать?

Comment: Смущает конструкция catch (MyError.class).
нельзя просто так?      this.myClass.initialize();
      Assert.fail("Should have thrown MyError");

Comment: @JVic, а зачем return в catch()?

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev автор писал `Я же просто поймаю ошибку и продолжу тест, нет?` я и добавил, что бы тест он не продолжил а завершил)